# JWT: Getting token manually

Tags: angularjs, laravel, token

I'm using jwt-auth for laravel, and angular-js on client side.

This is my typical http request:

```
.controller('LoginController', function($scope,$rootScope ,$auth, $state, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('api/loggedIn/getMe').success(function(data) {
                //do stuff
            }).error(function(error) {
                //do stuff
            });
    })
```

Every time i send $http request the token side is done automatically, but I want to make one request without using $http, so I need to include my jwt-auth token in headers manualy. (that's because I want to use Dropzone for file upload).

I have something like this:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
        // Pass token
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer: ' + /*This is where I want to put my token*/);
     }
};
```

Edit: this is screenshot from firebug:[image]

Edit: I figured out that satelizer does that nice thing for me, so $auth.getToken() did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that satelizer does that nice thing for me, so $auth.getToken() did the trick.